# SharePoint metadata not visible to users

Tags: security, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, metadata

I'm working on a dynamic page that does data lookups based on metadata in the term store. So I have a Managed Metadata column set up and I can use it to query lists and such with no problem. I also have an image library with a managed metadata column that I use to return relevant images.

The problem is that I, as a farm admin, can see and edit all the metadata in my image library. Normal users with read rights see a blank field. They get no results from the lookups, as if the metadata was blank. I even made a user a site collection admin and he can add metadata, but not see it in any view or the object property page. He only sees it on the edit page.

My metadata service is set up normally, the content hub is running without issue, no errors on the page. Publishing is disabled so it's not approval thing. Anyone seen anything like this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a list called TaxonomyHiddenList at the root site collection level that didn't have the right permissions for some reason. It should have had read rights for the NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users group but they were not there. I added them back and everything works OK.

Some kind of glitch during site collection creation I guess.

Comment: In my case, after migrating a site from SP 2010 --> 2013 --> 2016; that list still had "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated User", but it needed to re-added. It resolved differently to 
`c:0!.s|windows` "All Users (windows)"